# Template literal types includes all possible enums when used as fn prop call

Tags: typescript

What could be a reason for local type to be different from playground?

Was not able to reproduce this behaviour in playground even with similar tsconfig options.

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EtUAqDagAFYAAz6QzzBsVJPWhRKW3p+2ZjS8WSaOwxuTzHRq1XO0D2eaqv2q7YKtAOCaTXXoJBrUPaPQGiJGzq7kBrAD8GaI3tkcWBoPBTihMLhwUhyJSsMIZlMeGMfogA).

```ts
enum Options {
    ONE = 'one',
    TWO = 'two',
    THREE = 'three'
    // and more
}
    
export const add = <T extends Options>(list: T[]): `id_${T}`[] =>
    list.map((p) => `id_${p}` as const);

// local type and playground are same - ("id_one" | "id_two")[]
const result = add([Options.ONE, Options.TWO]) 

export const apiGet = async (): Promise<any> => ({
    options: {
        smth2: result, // correct type if used as value - ("id_one" | "id_two")[]
        // here playgroud (smth or add return type) type is - ("id_one" | "id_two")[]
        // but locally it's ("id_one" | "id_two" | ... 50 more ... | "id_three")[]
        // what is the difference for functon call assign and value assing?
        smth: add([Options.ONE, Options.TWO]),   
    }
});
```

tsconfig:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "lib": ["es2020"]
  },
```

Comment: Do you also use the same TypeScript version locally as the one used in Playground?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad i've tried 4.3.2/4.2.4 locally and lower playground verisons

Comment: Can you post contents of your `tsconfig.json` file? And `package.json` if it's a part of some project.

Comment: @aleksxor added

Comment: Well, still no luck. I cannot reproduce the problem.